# Coldfusion 10 Servlet issues

Tags: tomcat, servlets, coldfusion, web.xml, coldfusion-10

I'm currently experiencing problems with *ColdFusion* finding my servlet.  In *ColdFusion 9*, I would simply put it under the `wwwroot/WEB-INF/classes/` directory and *ColdFusion* would serve when requested.

In *ColdFusion 10* I've added the same Servlet in the `cfusion/wwwroot/WEB-INF/classes` directory (restarting afterwards) and it was not found when explicitly called.  I added the descriptor for it in the `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.myServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

and I'm still unable to call it.  Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is not a programming question, it's a server admin question, thus it belongs on [SF] not [SO].

Comment: I assume that in the web.xml you also added a servlet-mapping? Is anything written to the log files? Also, does the not-cound message look like the one form Tomcat or the one from Coldfusion? It could be that one of CF's servlet mappings is 'beating' yours?

Comment: barnyr - A file not found shows up in the log.  Sadly, nothing further.

Comment: Peter - I didn't even know that other site existed.  Thank You, I'll try there.

Answer (score 3):

It should be that your Java classes are compiled with higher versioned JRE than the ColdFusion's JRE.
Say your ColdFusion 10 is running on Java 1.6, and you have compiled your Java classes on Java1.7, these classes can't be loaded by ColdFusion. For it to be loaded you should have compiled them on Java1.6 itself or run ColdFusion on Java1.7